# Why objectWillChange has no effect

Tags: swift, combine

I got this sample code about ObservableObject from [Apple official website](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/observableobject)

```
import Foundation

class Contact: ObservableObject {
    @Published var name: String
    @Published var age: Int
    
    
    init(name: String, age: Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    }
    
    func changeAge() -> Int {
        self.age += 1
        return self.age
    }
}



class Test {
    init() {
        let john = Contact(name: "John Appleseed", age: 24)
        _ = john.objectWillChange
            .sink { _ in
                print("\(john.age) will change")
        }
        print(john.changeAge())
    }
}

let test = Test()
```

When running on terminal by `swift Contact.swift`, the result is only `25`, but official website shows the result should be

```
// Prints "24 will change"
// Prints "25"
```

Why the first line `Prints "24 will change"` is not shown?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to store the `AnyCancellable` that's returned by `sink`, otherwise it cancels the subscription as soon as it's deinitialized when you assign to `_`.

In your simple example just assigning to a local variable is enough to get the printout that you want, because the variable still lives when you change the age:

```
let c = john.objectWillChange.sink {...}
```

But in a real app, you'd want to assign it to a property, which would keep the subscription for the duration that you need. Typically, it's done like this:

```
class Test {
    private var c: Set<AnyCancellable> = []
    init() {
        let john = Contact(name: "John Appleseed", age: 24)
        john.objectWillChange
            .sink { _ in
                print("\(john.age) will change")
            }
            .store(in: &c) // store here
        print(john.changeAge())
    }
}
```

Comment: `import Combine` may be needed for the declaration of `AnyCancellable`

Comment: Interesting and yes, this was my issue too! Basically not holding on to an `AnyCancellable` makes the object not receive callbacks/sink responses (whatever you wanna call 'em).